# How to Calculate the Position of a Button base on the position of the window

Tags: python, winapi, pyautogui

Im having trouble figuring out how to calculate the x/y position of where a button is depending on the location of the window on my screen

currently I have it hard-coded the button location for pyautogui to click but If I move the window now that position is incorrect and would like to make it so it updates the location of the button depending on where the window is on the monitor

using win32 I can get the location of the window like this

```
window_handle = FindWindow(none, 'myWindow')
window_rect = GetWIndowRect(window_handle)
print(window_rect)
#returns (237, 286, 583, 850)
```

button location is `x:505 y:787`

What would be the correct way to calculate this or is there a built-in function to do this

Comment: Use `ScreenToClient` to convert to client coordinates, example `left, top = win32gui.ScreenToClient(hwnd, (left,top) )`

Comment: Use `backend="uia"` and you won't have to fiddle with coordinates. That's how [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) is intended to be used.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani thanks exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @IInspectable I wasn't able to figure out how to use ``` backend="uia"``` I tried looking at the program using stuff like spy++ and windows built-in tool I forgot the name of it to inspect the program wasn't able to get any of the buttons (might be because I wasn't doing it right)

Comment: Use [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects).